# EXEC_BAD_ACCESS(Code=1)

Tags: objective-c, ios

Everything was working fine till I added a new NSNUmber variable.

My .h file looks has this -

```
NSNumber *foodPriceTotal;
@property (assign, readwrite) NSNumber *foodPriceTotal;
```

and in my .m file I have -

```
@synthesize foodPriceTotal;
```

In my Initwithnibname method I do this -

```
foodPriceTotal = [[NSNumber alloc] init];
```

In my cellForRowAtIndexPath function I do this

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
CGFloat deliveryCharge = [prefs floatForKey:@"deliveryCharge"];
foodPriceTotal = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:([foodPriceTotal floatValue] + deliveryCharge)];
```

I get error EXEC_BAD_ACCESS(Code=1) when I scroll up and down -

The erring line is -

```
foodPriceTotal = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:([foodPriceTotal floatValue] + deliveryCharge)];
```

Any idea please?

Comment: You may want to use a strong or weak property for your `NSNumber` instance (`foodPriceTotal`) but not assign.

Comment: Thanks Till. Upvoted you for your comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Till pointed out, your ownership qualifier (`assign`) is not what you want here. In 99% with `NSNumber` you want `copy` instead.

Then later, use the accessor method:

```
self.foodPriceTotal = ...
```

No reason to put that `NSNumber *foodPriceTotal` declaration into your .h file at all, just delete that line.

Regarding your `init` method, you might want to rethink about your logic. What is a number without any value here? Probably `nil` is just as good and much clearer.

Comment: Thanks Eiko and Till. I need to read more about ownership qualifiers. But your suggestion fixed my issue.